# How to import WorkManager class

Tags: android

I have this:

```
import android.arch.*;

public class ScrollingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private PeriodicWorkRequest notificationWorkSingle;
    private WorkManager mWorkManager;

}
```

I love how not a single tutorial shows us which class to import

How to import `PeriodicWorkRequest` and `WorkManager`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A small addition to the answer by Alexander Mills:
Here's the link to the official docs on how to add Architecture Components to your project -> 
[Adding Components to your Project](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/adding-components)

Answer (score 4):

Of course:

```
import androidx.work.WorkManager;
import androidx.work.PeriodicWorkRequest;
```

and use this in build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation "android.arch.work:work-runtime:1.0.0-beta02"
}
```

and

```
dependencies {
    classpath "android.arch.work:work-runtime:1.0.0-beta02"
}
```